# github 'resolve conflicts' button disabled

Tags: github

I'm an admin on this repo. In this PR I have removed multiple files and merged these changes from local to origin/develop. When merging origin/develop to origin/master I'm getting this conflict for one of the four files I've removed. Our flow is always local to origin/develop to origin/master. I had no conflicts when mergin local to origin/develop.
Github won't let me resolve the conflict.

Questions:

1. Why is the  'Resolve Conflicts' button disabled? I've never seen this before.
2. Why would this one file have a merge conflict? It's one of 3 config files that I removed completely in this PR.
3. Why am I getting this conflict on origin/develop to origin/master when I had no conflicts on local to origin/develop?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If the Resolve conflicts button is deactivated, your pull request's merge conflict is too complex to resolve on GitHub Enterprise or the site administrator has disabled the conflict editor for pull requests between repositories. You must resolve the merge conflict using another Git client like Atom's Git integration or the command line.

Comment: How is a one-liner in the package.json too complex? This looks like a GitHub issue.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is little old post. But putting my answer as I also faced the same issue and I could solve it using following.

As shown in screenshot attached, you can solve this on your local using command line.

1. Fetch the branch which has conflicts. (say `master` branch)
2. Checkout to that branch.
3. Pull the code from another branch you want to merge it into. (Take a pull from `develop` into `master` )
4. OR Rebase the branch as: checkout to develop branch, then take pull into it `git pull origin develop`. Then checkout to master branch and do `git rebase develop`.
5. Now resolve the conflicts, add the changed files, commit it, push onto the branch you want to merge it into (in this case `master` ). It might happen that you don't have permission to do it. In that case you can push this branch on your fork, and then raise PR to main repo)

There is one more method.

Using [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/). Just that, it is not available for linux from official site.
For this you can check this [link](https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop).
Read the instructions in the README doc and install it accordingly.

And you can find the method to solve the conflicts using GitHub Desktop [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIVW0sijSjY).

Comment: "Take a pull", this step isn't clear. `git pull main` results in `fatal: 'main' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: @TravisD First check if you have that branch on your local. If not, fetch it and then take pull.
Also check your command. It should be `git pull <remote-name> <branch-name>` e.g. `git pull origin main`